# How to Install Laravel 5.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, php, laravel, composer

As what I have stated from the title,

I need to install the newest laravel 5.3 in 14.04 server, the composer cannot run because it need PHP 5.6 but in my own server they have 5.5. Either, I have to upgrade the PHP (which I have stuck because I cannot find the right tutorials) or I use Laravel 5.2 which I cannot do it because I have 5.3 in my locals and my GIT repository.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

To install PHP 5.6 in Ubuntu 14.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php5.6
```

#### Install Composer

```
sudo apt install curl  
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php   
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later composer can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install composer
```

#### Create Laravel application:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel [foldername]
```

<sup>Replace `[foldername]` with the name of the directory you want your new Laravel application installed to. It must not exist before installation. You may also need to add the Composer executable to your system path.</sup>

#### Run Laravel application:

```
php artisan serve
```

<sub>**References:** 

• [Laravel 5.3 Installation Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation)

• [Laravel 5.3 Homestead Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead) - Laravel Homestead is an official, prepackaged Vagrant box that provides a development environment without requiring you to install PHP, a web server, and any other server software on your local machine.</sub>

Comment: in a tutorial, we have to install such as php5-fpm etc, is there any additional or another package we have to install?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 I often follow this tutorial, and I am confused because this package allows me only to install laravel 5.2 because the PHP is 5.5, do you know how to adjust?